# Ubuntu 14.10: Error while reading from descriptor - broken pipe

Tags: boot, nvidia

Every time when i start my laptop i'll get this error message

```
Error while reading from descriptor - broken pipe
```

I don't know what to do. I think my graphic card cause this problem, because the graphic card don't show up at additional drivers. Also the Pc boots very slow. I already did some settings like changin swappiness and Startprogramms.
My graphic card are the `NVIDIA® GeForce® 840M, 2 GB DDR3`

Answer (score 0):

looks like a common issue for ubuntu 14.10.. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1364630